# Olly hangs and lags

Tags: ollydbg

For some reason whether I open a program or attach to it, sometimes Olly 2 will behave really weird. It will either freeze and hang forever when I do things like placing a breakpoint, or more commonly, I will be able to see the screen render. When Olly jumps to a code area out of reach of the screen, I will be able to see how the screen is drawn over 0.5 second or so, from the top and downwards. If I put on single step animation, Olly will stay around 1 second on each line before moving onto the next, as if something is lagging terribly. Even clicking on another line takes a considerable amount of time before the line gets selected.  I restart the program over and over in Olly and suddenly it just works. Any ideas what might be the problem? I have tried to delete the .udd files and sometimes it works, other times it won't. Needless to say this is extremely annoying and doing simple things like placing a breakpoint keeps me waiting, so it makes it impossible to do real-time debugging. This has not been a problem with Immunity and Olly 1 as much, but I want to use Olly 2.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to make it less like a wall of text. There's a lot of unnecessary information.